Copy file failed in Dockerfile
FROM docker-repo.frontiir.net/container-images/py38-poetry:1.3-slim-bullseye

ENV APP_WORKDIR=/app 

WORKDIR ${APP_WORKDIR}

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --quiet --no-root --only=main --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-cache

RUN ls -al ./src/

COPY ./src/ .

RUN poetry install --only-root --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-cache

CMD [ "example", "--version"]


I have a src folder on the same level as this dockerfile. Also, I've checked ls -al ./src/ and it is not empty. But when I run that ls -al ./src/ in the dockerfile and build, it shows me an error that the src folder is empty.
I want the src folder to be copied on the docker images.

Your previous command WORKDIR made /app as current dir. So, your current dir is /app, and you try to run RUN ls -al /app/src/. There is obviiously no src/ in /app yet.

...and when you do COPY you copy the contents of src into the current directory, not a src subdirectory.  COPY's syntax can be a little subtle as to when it's copying the directory as opposed to its contents; I might write COPY src/ src/ making sure both paths end with slashes.
